# How do I make the text search as a module in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, pattern-matching, text-search

```
with open('fin.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if text in line:print line
    searchfile.close()
```

the keyword 'text' used in line is assumed to be the word that the user looks for in a paragraph.
Can someone tell me how I can turn this function as a module?
**DO Tell me how to have PDF files as an input to it**
Thank you
P.S: I am new to Python

Comment: 1. That's not a function. 2. You don't need to close the file, that will happen automatically when you leave the `with` block. 3. Why do you want to make a module for such a simple piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
def text_searcher( text, file_name ):
    with open( file_name, 'r' ) as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if text in line:print line
```

Save this file as `text_search.py`. You can then import it as a module in any other Python file in the same directory by using :

`from text_search import text_searcher`

Or you can use it with:

```
import text_search
text_search.text_searcher( text, "fin.txt" )
```

Please note that in this case the file to be searched in must also be in the same directory.

Comment: Can you please tell me how we could input a PDF file for the same?